# Solo muestra undefined los valores capturados en los inputs

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tratando de capturar dos valores a través de dos ***input***, uno es texto y el otro es para fecha. Trato de hacer esto, con una ventana ***modal*** la cual aparece al presionar un botón. El código es el siguiente:

#### calendarioestu.html

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
    <a href="#/menuestu" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></a>
    <p class="title">Calendario</p>
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-plus-outline" ng-     click="modal.show()"></button>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-view>
    <ion-content has-header="true">
        <div class="list">

            <div class="item item-divider">
            Tareas
            </div>

        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

#### modalestu.html

```
<ion-modal-view>

<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Nueva Tarea</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cerrar</button>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content>

    <div class="list">

        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Tarea</span>
          <input  placeholder="Tarea" type="text" ng-model="tareatxt">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Fecha</span>
          <input  type="date" ng-model="fechatxt">
        </label>

        <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="agregarTareas()">Crear</button>

    </div>

</ion-content>

</ion-modal-view>
```

#### calendarioestu.js

```
angular.module('calendarioEstu', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.controller('tareasEstu', tareasEstu);

 tareasEstu.$inject = ['$scope', '$ionicModal'];

 function tareasEstu($scope, $ionicModal) {

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('Templates/Estudiante/modalestu.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});

$scope.agregarTareas = function() {

    var datosTarea, fechaDigitada;

    datosTarea = {
        Tarea: $scope.tareatxt,
        Fecha: $scope.fechatxt
    };

    console.log(datosTarea.Tarea + " - " + datosTarea.Fecha);

    if (typeof datosTarea.tarea === 'undfined' || typeof datosTarea.fecha === 'undefined') {

        console.log("Deben estar ambos campos llenos");

    } else {

        fechaDigitada = moment(new Date(datosTarea.fecha)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        console.log(fechaDigitada + " - " + datosTarea.tarea);

    }

}

};
```

Si los campos están llenos o vacios, me muestra esto por consola

```
undefined - undefined 
Deben estar ambos campos llenos
```

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]
[image: Imagen de la tablet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El origen del problema es que `$ionicModal` **siempre** crea siempre un `$scope` nuevo basandose en [tus opciones](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/#initialize) cuando ejecutas

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(template, {
    scope: ...
    animation: ...
    focusFirstInput: ...
    backdropClickToClose: ...
    hardwareBackButtonClose: ...
});
```

Si la opción **`scope`** está presente el modal creará un hijo de ese `$scope` de lo contrario creará un hijo del `$rootScope`. De una forma u otra los bindings en la plantilla del modal nunca se establecen en el `$scope` que manipulas sino en un hijo de este.

Esto hace que caigas en un problema conocido como el ***dot notation*** que básicamente hace que en lugar de modificar las propiedades de tu `$scope` modifiques las de su hijo por lo que cuando intentas obtener sus valores esperando que estas se encuentren presentes siempre son undefined.

Debes recordar que los objetos `$scope` son objetos de javascript puro y que la herencia prototípica de javascript funciona en ellos también ya que angular siempre define un objeto `$scope` del que heredar excepto para `$rootScope` cuyo padre es null (y solo hereda de [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)). El método [$scope.$new()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) es el que se usa internamente para lograr que dicha herencia funcione.

En el siguiente snippet tengo dos controllers uno dentro de otro lo que me crea dos `$scopes` que heredan entre sí y se muestra el binding tanto en el padre como en el hijo. Ambos obtienen bien el valor pero cuando lo modificas solo cambia el del hijo ya que lo que ocurre es que se **crea** una nueva propiedad en lugar de actualizar la propiedad del padre.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('PadreCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.valor = '10';
  })
  .controller('HijoCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PadreCtrl">
  Padre {{valor}}
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="HijoCtrl">
    Hijo {{valor}}
    <hr>
    <input ng-model="valor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes leer un poco más sobre el tema en la pregunta

[$scope vs. this en angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11323/scope-vs-this-en-angularjs)

***La solución***

Crea una nueva **propiedad** en tu `$scope` y usa esta propiedad para manipular los valores.

***¿Porqué funciona esto?***

Pues porque cuando intentes asignar

```
$scope.propiedad = valor;
```

La **cadena de herencia** no es consultada pues lo que estas haciendo es crear una propiedad nueva. Si en su lugar ejecutas

```
$scope.objeto.propiedad = valor;
```

En este caso el javascript intentará encontrar una propiedad llamada `objeto` dentro del `$scope` y al no encontrarse comenzará a buscarlo en su padre, en el padre de este y así sucesivamente hasta que lo encuentre consultando la **cadena de herencia** completa mientras no encuentre dicha propiedad.

No olvides inicializar el objeto

```
$scope.objeto = {};
```

El `$scope` de tu controller tiene dicha propiedad y esta es usada para asignar los valores dandote el resultado que esperas.

Aquí te dejo un plunker y un demo funcionando

http://plnkr.co/edit/mTvXZX?p=preview

```js
angular.module('calendarioEstu', ['ionic'])
  .controller('tareasEstu', tareasEstu);

tareasEstu.$inject = ['$scope', '$ionicModal'];

function tareasEstu($scope, $ionicModal) {
  // Esta es la propiedad a usar
  $scope.nueva = {};

  $scope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate('<ion-modal-view>' +
  '<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">' +
    '<h1 class="title">Nueva Tarea</h1>' +
    '<button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Cerrar</button>' +
  '</ion-header-bar>' +
  '<ion-content>' +
    '<div class="list">' +
      '<label class="item item-input">' +
        '<span class="input-label">Tarea</span>' +
        '<input placeholder="Tarea" type="text" ng-model="nueva.tareatxt">' +
      '</label>' +
      '<label class="item item-input">' +
        '<span class="input-label">Fecha</span>' +
        '<input type="date" ng-model="nueva.fechatxt">' +
      '</label>' +
      '<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="agregarTareas()">Crear</button>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</ion-content>' +
'</ion-modal-view>', {
    scope: $scope
  });

  $scope.agregarTareas = function() {
    var datosTarea, fechaDigitada;
    datosTarea = {
      Tarea: $scope.nueva.tareatxt,
      Fecha: $scope.nueva.fechatxt
    };

    console.log(datosTarea.Tarea + " - " + datosTarea.Fecha);
    if (typeof datosTarea.Tarea === 'undefined' || typeof datosTarea.Fecha === 'undefined') {
      alert("Deben estar ambos campos llenos");
    } else {
      fechaDigitada = moment(new Date(datosTarea.Fecha)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      alert(fechaDigitada + " - " + datosTarea.Tarea);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="calendarioEstu" ng-controller="tareasEstu">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
    <a href="#/menuestu" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></a>
    <p class="title">Calendario</p>
    <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-plus-outline" ng-click="modal.show()"></button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-view>
    <ion-content has-header="true">
      <div class="list">
        <div class="item item-divider">
          Tareas
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Según veo, es un problema con el `$scope`.

Tal como aparece en la [documentación](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/), el modal no accede directamente a las variables del `$scope`, por lo que no puede escribirlas.

Te recomiendo agregar a tu función `agregarTareas` un parámetro, que sea el modelo de la tarea que estás creando dentro del modal, de la misma forma que el ejemplo:

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Tarea</span>
  <input  placeholder="Tarea" type="text" ng-model="nueva_tarea.tareatxt">
</label>

<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label">Fecha</span>
  <input  type="date" ng-model="nueva_tarea.fechatxt">
</label>

<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="agregarTareas(nueva_tarea)">Crear</button>
```

y tu función agregarTareas:

```
$scope.agregarTareas = function(tarea) {
  var datosTarea, fechaDigitada;

  datosTarea = {
    Tarea: tarea.tareatxt,
    Fecha: tarea.fechatxt
  };

  console.log(datosTarea.Tarea + " - " + datosTarea.Fecha);

  if (typeof datosTarea.tarea === 'undefined' || typeof datosTarea.fecha === 'undefined') {
    console.log("Deben estar ambos campos llenos");
  } else {
    fechaDigitada = moment(new Date(datosTarea.fecha)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(fechaDigitada + " - " + datosTarea.tarea);
  }
}
```

Comment: voy a probar lo que recomiendas, y luego te digo que tal