# ng-model no funciona en el ng-repeat de angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
usuarios:{
    {name:pepe, telefonos:{movil:166666666, movil2:66852147}}, 
    {name:paco, telefonos:{movil:66666666, movil2:66852147}} 
}
```

y mi **index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController"> 
     <div ng-repeat="user in usuarios">  
         {{user.name}} 
         <div ng-repeat="phone in user.telefonos">
             <input type="text" name="movil1" ng-model="movil1" ng-value="{phone.movil1}}">
             <input type="text" name="movil2" ng-model="movil2" ng-value="{phone.movil2}}"> 
         </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="movil3" ng-model="movil3" ng-value="6555555">
</div>
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto, funciona, PERO, en mi controlador si hago esto:

```
console.log($scope.movil1) => sale undefined
```

sin embargo hago esto:

```
console.log($scope.movil3) => sale el valor
```

Tiene que ver algo con el repeat

Alguna sugerencia?

Un saludo

Comment: Deberías incluir el código de tu controlador. Por otro lado, en el JSON que posteaste dice movil sin el 1.

Comment: Tu json tiene errores. Lo que parece un objeto debería ser un arreglo. Las propiedades tampoco coinciden con los valores que bindeas. Que estas tratando de hacer exactamente?

Comment: Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque la directiva `ng-repeat` crea un `$scope` por cada elemento de la iteración por lo que cuando dices `ng-model = "movil1"` no te estas refiriendo a la propiedad `movil1` del `$scope` de tu controlador sino a uno de los hijos que crea `ng-repeat`.

Para solucionar esto debes usar un objeto en tu controlador para no incurrir en el problema del *dot notation*. Lee

[$scope vs. this en angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11323/scope-vs-this-en-angularjs/11362#11362)

En tu caso tienes un arreglo de usuarios por lo que si bindeas directamente tendrás todos tus inputs modificando exactamente el mismo valor. Debes usar un arreglo o un objeto para que el binding se haga en lugares diferentes.

También para inicializar el valor del modelo debes usar `ng-init` en lugar de `ng-value`

*Usando un arreglo*

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.datos = [];

    $scope.usuarios = [{
      name: 'pepe',
      telefonos: {
        movil: 166666666,
        movil2: 66852147
      }
    }, {
      name: 'paco',
      telefonos: {
        movil: 66666666,
        movil2: 66852147
      }
    }];

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log($scope.datos);
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
    {{usuario.name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="datos[$index].movil1" ng-init="datos[$index].movil1 = usuario.telefonos.movil">
    <input type="text" name="movil2" ng-model="datos[$index].movil2" ng-init="datos[$index].movil2 = usuario.telefonos.movil2">
  </div>
</div>
```

*Usando un objeto*

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.datos = {};

    $scope.usuarios = [{
      name: 'pepe',
      telefonos: {
        movil: 166666666,
        movil2: 66852147
      }
    }, {
      name: 'paco',
      telefonos: {
        movil: 66666666,
        movil2: 66852147
      }
    }];

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log($scope.datos);
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
    {{usuario.name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="datos[usuario.name].movil1" ng-init="datos[usuario.name].movil1 = usuario.telefonos.movil">
    <input type="text" name="movil2" ng-model="datos[usuario.name].movil2" ng-init="datos[usuario.name].movil2 = usuario.telefonos.movil2">
  </div>
</div>
```