# ¿Como paso datos entre controladores?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Quiero hacer una barra de navegación en mi web, entonces, en el index quiero poner la sección en la que se encuentra el usuario.

El problema que tengo es que no se como puedo pasarle la variable al MasterController desde el Controller de cada vista, para que al cambiar de sección se cambie en el index automáticamente.

Os pego el link del ejemplo que estoy usando.

Master Controller

```
angular.module('RDash')
    .controller('MasterCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', MasterCtrl]);

function MasterCtrl($scope, $cookieStore) {
    /**
     * Sidebar Toggle & Cookie Control
     */
    var mobileView = 992;

    $scope.getWidth = function() {
        return window.innerWidth;
    };

    $scope.$watch($scope.getWidth, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue >= mobileView) {
            if (angular.isDefined($cookieStore.get('toggle'))) {
                $scope.toggle = ! $cookieStore.get('toggle') ? false : true;
            } else {
                $scope.toggle = true;
            }
        } else {
            $scope.toggle = false;
        }

    });

    $scope.toggleSidebar = function() {
        $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
        $cookieStore.put('toggle', $scope.toggle);
    };

    window.onresize = function() {
        $scope.$apply();
    };
}
```

Controlador

```
/**
 * Alerts Controller
 */

angular
    .module('RDash')
    .controller('AlertsCtrl', ['$scope', AlertsCtrl]);

function AlertsCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.alerts = [{
        type: 'success',
        msg: 'Thanks for visiting! Feel free to create pull requests to improve the dashboard!'
    }, {
        type: 'danger',
        msg: 'Found a bug? Create an issue with as many details as you can.'
    }];

    $scope.addAlert = function() {
        $scope.alerts.push({
            msg: 'Another alert!'
        });
    };

    $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };
}
```

La cosa sería que el master modifica el index, es el único, tendría que saber como pasarle un parámetro desde el controlador con la sección a la que corresponde cada controlador.

Gracias!

Comment: Especifica un poco como lo has implementado (no me dice nada que tengas un MasterCrontroller y otros en otras vistas). Peganos el HTML, haz un fiddle, danos un ejemplo parecido a tu caso con el que podamos ayudarte... de otra forma, complicado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa el `$rootScope`. Recuerda que todos los controladores tienen un `$scope` y dicho `$scope` hereda las propiedades del `$rootScope` y este funciona en la vista también.

No voy a reproducir tu código pero te pondré un ejemplo que ilustra lo que digo

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        template: '<h1>{{global.valor}}</h1><p><a href="#/next">Siguiente</a></p>',
        controller: 'PrimerCtrl'
      })
      .when('/next', {
        template: '<h1>{{global.valor}}</h1><p><a href="#/last">Siguiente</a></p>',
        controller: 'SegundoCtrl'
      })
      .when('/last', {
        template: '<h1>{{global.valor}}</h1>',
        controller: 'TercerCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
  .controller('PrimerCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.global.valor = 1;
  })
  .controller('SegundoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.global.valor = 2;
  })
  .controller('TercerCtrl', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.global.valor = 3;
  })
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.global = {};
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

En todos los casos el valor que se está mostrando/modificando es el del `$rootScope` aunque yo lo haga con `$scope.global`. Ese es el sistema de herencia haciendo su función.

Ten cuidado cuando ejecutes directamente del `$scope.propiedad` pues si no usas un objeto puedes que no te funcione. Si quieres estar seguro del todo inyecta el `$rootScope` y manipúlalo directamente ahí.

Comment: Ni siquiera $scope debe usarse a la ligera... $rootScope no debería ser tocado en prácticamente ningún caso. Lo suyo sería que usase una factoría...

Comment: @Astaroth Usar un Factory es añadir una capa de abstracción. Eso no es mala idea siempre y cuando tenga sentido pero el resultado es básicamente el mismo. Recuerda que `$rootScope` es simplemente un objeto, la razón por la que lo hacen inyectable es para que puedas manipularlo. Siempre que estés consciente de los problemas del dot notation y no incurras en ellos te irá bien. Lee http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11323/scope-vs-this-en-angularjs/11362#11362

Comment: Tú mismo lo dices, lleva a buenas prácticas, a código mucho más fácil de entender, evita dependencias innecesarias y... ¿he mencionado las buenas prácticas? ¿el antiñapismo? Bajo mi opinión... no se debe tocar, y no soy el único que lo cree (a no ser que vayas a hacer broadcast/on/emit de un evento).

Los singletos son feos y están considerados un antipatrón, pero son mejor opción que tirar de $scope/$rootScope a la mínima. Y no hablemos de facilidad de testeo, modularización, etc.

Comment: @Astaroth A lo que me refiero es al principio [KISS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS). No será la primera vez que veré crear una montaña de código solo para modificar una propiedad en un objeto. Si este es el caso usar `$scope` y `$rootScope` **ES** una buena idea. Ninguna practica es buena si lleva a realizar una acción más complicada sin un buen motivo. Tanto el `$scope` como el `$rootScope` son testeables y van ligados a tu controller. Crear un Factory para modificar el `$rootScope` puede ser buena idea, crear uno para el `$scope` es casi siempre una mala idea.