# Por que me crea las propiedades en el scope equivocado entre controllers padre e hijos

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Buenos días. El caso es este, tengo esta vista html:

```
<!-- VISTA HOME/INDEX -->

<div ng-controller="generalView" class="index">

    <!--  as vm -->
    <div class="container-fluid mainContainer">
        <div class="row" style=" margin-top: .5em;">

            <div class="col-xs-2 sideBar" id="mainGrl" ng-cloak>

                <h2><a href="#" onclick="collapseMainGrl();" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff;">@Resources.Translate.general</a></h2>
                <div ng-include=" '/Home/mainGeneral'"> </div>

            </div> <!-- Main General // 2 columnas -->

            <img class="imgTenarisLogo" src="/Images/Tenaris_Logo.png" style="width:1000px; margin-top:6em;" ng-show="showLogo" ng-cloak />



            <div class="col-xs-10" ng-show="statusShow" id="zoneFilters" ng-cloak>

                <!--  VISTA MUESTRA -->
                <div class="row" id="vistaMuestra" ng-if="showES">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 " id="panel-body" ng-show="statusShow">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="#" style="position: absolute; text-decoration: none; color:#fff ; right: 97%;" onclick="collapseMainGrl();">
                                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'>
                                </i>
                            </a>

                            <a href="" data-target="#filtersCollapse" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff; margin-left:-20px; position:absolute" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="collapseFilter()">
                                @Resources.Translate.filter
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff ; float:right;" ng-click="showMills()" id="">
                                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-retweet' style="padding:0.3em">
                                </i>
                            </a><i style="float: right; color: white;">@Session["mill"] </i>
                        </h2>


                   @*     <div class="collapse in" id="filtersCollapse">*@
                            <!-- FILTROS MUESTRA -->
                            <div ng-controller="filterControllerES">
                                <form ng-if="showES" name="filtrosMuestra">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">

                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.expedient</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="expedientSearchES" ng-model="filterES.Expedient" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" />{{input_Expedient}}</td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> @Resources.Translate.cycle</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="cycleSearchES" ng-model="filterES.Cycle" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" />{{input_Cycle}}</td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> @Resources.Translate.heat</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="heatSearchES" ng-model="filterES.Heat" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" />{{Heat}}</td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> @Resources.Translate.Lot</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="lotSearchES" ng-model="filterES.Lot" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" />{{lot}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.OIS</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="OISSearchES" ng-model="filterES.OIS" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" /></td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.HTR</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="HTRSearchES" ng-model="filterES.HTR" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" /></td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.origin</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2">
                                                <select class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" name="originSearchES" ng-model="filterES.Origin">
                                                    <option value="value_0">....</option>
                                                    <option value="value_1"> origen_1 </option>
                                                    <option value="value_2"> origen_2 </option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.modifier</th> <!-- attr sampler -->
                                            <td class="col-xs-2">
                                                <multiselect name="SelectionModifier[]" multiple="true" id="mult" ng-model="filterES.SelectionModifier" options="mod.desc for mod in ListModifiers">
                                                </multiselect>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.dateFrom</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2">
                                                <input type="text" ui-date="dateOptions" ui-date-format="dd/mm/yy" name="DateFromSearch" ng-model="filterES.DateFrom" style="cursor:pointer" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" value="{{aDate}}" />
                                                @*<valida-fechas fecha="filterES.DateTo" fecha2="filterES.DateFrom" ng-model="filterES"></valida-fechas>
                        <span ng-show="filtrosMuestra.DateFromSearch.$invalid">NIF no válido.</span>*@

                                            </td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.dateTo </th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2">
                                                <input type="text" data-ui-date="dateOptions" name="DateToSearchES" ui-date-format="dd/mm/yy" ng-model="filterES.DateTo" style="cursor:pointer" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" value="{{aDate}}" />

                                            </td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.idSampler</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" name="idSamplerSearchES" ng-model="filterES.IdSampler" class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" /></td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.typeSampler</th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2">

                                                <multiselect name="SelectionModifier[]" multiple="true" id="mult" ng-model="filterES.Selection" options="mod.desc for mod in ListTipoMuestra">
                                                </multiselect>
                                            </td>


                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader">@Resources.Translate.hamper </th>
                                            <td class="col-xs-2">
                                                <select class="col-xs-2 inputInlineEdit" name="hamperSearchES" ng-model="filterES.Hamper" disabled>
                                                    <option value="value_0">....</option>
                                                    <option value="value_1"> testing </option>
                                                    <option value="value_2"> Aca multiSelect Angular </option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>

                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> </th>
                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> </th>
                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> </th>
                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> </th>
                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> </th>
                                            <th class="col-xs-1 backgroundGrey fontSize11 colorColumnHeader"> </th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <!-- BOTONES BUSCAR LIMPIAR EXPORTAR MUESTRA -->
                            <div class="btn-general">
                                <button id="btnSearchGrl" class="btn btn-default search" ng-click="btnSearchGrl(this)">          @Resources.Translate.search </button>
                                <button id="btnReset" class="btn btn-default reset" ng-click="btnReset(this)" type="reset"> @Resources.Translate.reset  </button>
                                <button id="btnExport" class="btn btn-default excelExport" ng-click="excelExport(this)">           @Resources.Translate.export </button>
                            </div>
                       <!--  </div> -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- TABLA DATOS MUESTRA -->
                    <ng-controller ng-controller="tableControllerES">
                        <div class="col-xs-12" id="sectionTable">


                            <div ng-if="showES" ng-init="gridOnload()">
                                <h4 id="table1" style="margin-top:.09em;">

                                    <label class="buttonShowAll" ng-class="{disabled: btnShowState}" ng-click="showAllColumns(btnShowState)">
                                        Mostrar Columnas
                                        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-check' style="padding:0.3em">  </i>
                                    </label>
                                    <label style="margin-left:45px;position:absolute;">  @Resources.Translate.sampler </label>
                                </h4>

                                <div ui-grid="samplerGridES" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-cellnav ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-column-resizer class="grid" style="height: 217px;">  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div ng-show="statusShow" ng-cloak>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 tableSampler" id="zoneTabs">

                                <div id="tabSamplerDetails">
                                    <h4> @Resources.Translate.details</h4>

                                    <ul id="NavsTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">

                                        <li> <a href=" #" ng-if="tabGeneralEvents" ng-class="btnEventos" ng-click="setTabGeneralEvents()">@Resources.Translate.events</a> </li>
                                        <li> <a href="#" ng-if="tabProduct" ng-class="btnProd" ng-click="setTabProduct()">         @Resources.Translate.product    </a> </li>
                                        <li> <a href="#" ng-if="tabSampler" ng-class="btnMuestra" ng-click="setTabSampler()">         @Resources.Translate.sampler    </a> </li>
                                        <li> <a href="#" ng-if="tabSpecimen" ng-class="btnProbeta" ng-click="setTabSpecimen()">        @Resources.Translate.specimen   </a> </li>
                                        <li> <a href="#" ng-if="tabTest" ng-class="btnEnsayo" ng-click="setTabTest()">            @Resources.Translate.test       </a> </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!-- PANELES DETALLES MUESTRA -->
                                <div class="tblIncludes">
                                    <!-- tab EVENTOS -->
                                    <div>
                                        <div ng-if="isGeneralEvent == 'ES'" class="generalEvent" ng-include="'/EventSampler/GeneralEvents'"> </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!--  tab PRODUCTO-->
                                    <div>
                                        <div ng-if="isProduct == 'ES'" ng-include="'/EventSampler/tabProduct'"> </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Tab MUESTRA -->
                                    <div>
                                        <div ng-if="isSampler == 'ES'" ng-include="'/EventSampler/tabSampler'"> </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-controller>

                </div>


            </div>

            <!-- VISTA VISUALIZACION DE ENSAYOS -->
            <div class="col-xs-10" ng-if="showInc" id="homeVT">
                <div ng-include="'/visualizationTests/Index'"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Modal: para devolver mensajes de error -->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" id="modalResponseFail" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content kkuat">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Fail Response</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body" id="errorMsgFail"></div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>

            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->


</div>  <!-- cierre: ng-app="index" -->
```

Como verán tengo dos controllers `filterControllerES` y `tableControllerES`, estos a su vez heredan de el controller padre `generalView` que esta al principio del bloque.

Yo intento crear una variable en el `$scope` de `generalView` desde `filterControllerES` de esta forma:

```
$scope.$parent.filterES = new FilterEventSampler({});
```

Ya que en teoría el único padre de `filterControllerES` es `generalView`. La cuestión es que no me la crea.

Me puse a analizar con Angularjs Batarang y encontré que la variable `filterES` la crea en otro lado:

[image: imagen de batarang]

La crea en

```
 <scope.$id=6>
```

Por que se creo ahí la variable?

Entonces para crear la variable en `generalView` tengo que codear:

```
    $scope.$parent.$parent.filterES = new FilterEventSampler({});
```

En este caso SI funciona.

Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recuerda que muchas directivas como `ng-if` y `ng-repeat` también crean scopes.

En tu caso tienes

```
ng-controller="generalView"                => $scope
    ng-if="showES"                         => $scope.$id = 6 // Este es el que ves
        ng-controller="filterControllerES" => $scope
```

Para que no tengas que estar haciendo `$parent.$parent.$parent...` puedes usar el sistema de herencia de angular y crear las propiedades en objetos en lugar de hacerlo directamente en el `$scope`

```
$scope.filter = { };

$scope.filter.filterES = new FilterEventSampler({});
```

De esta forma no importa cuantos niveles tengas siempre accederás a la propiedad correcta, siempre y cuando no la ocultes en los niveles inferiores con algo como

```
 $scope.filter = { };

 var $hijo = $scope.$new();

 $hijo.filter = 'valor';
```

El valor de `$scope.filter` no se eliminará pero no podrás accederlo en los scopes hijos. Esto te puede ocurrir en la vista automáticamente con directivas como `ng-model` y `ng-init` así que siempre trata de usar propiedades diferentes entre controllers padre-hijos.

Es importante que entiendas que si haces una directiva que tenga scope isolado y tratas de acceder a las propiedades del `$parent` no funcionará ya que estas directivas no heredan de nadie. A pesar de eso puedes aún acceder al `$rootScope` usando la propiedad `$root`.

Recapitulando las directivas con scope isolado son las que se crean con un **objeto** en la configuración `scope` o en `bindToController`

```
return {
    scope: { /* bindings*/}
}

// Si usas controller y bindToController

return {
    controller: '...',
    controllerAs: '...'
    bindToController: { /* bindings*/ }
}
```

Sólo usa el dot notation a tu favor.

Lee [$scope vs. this en angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11323/scope-vs-this-en-angularjs/11362#11362)