# AngularJS me devuelve UNDEFINED en el RETURN

Tags: javascript, json

Sucede que tengo esta función, la cual me deberia devover un `string` en `JSON`, pero no es asi, me devuelve `undefined`, porque?

```
$scope.get = function(id, tabla){
          var data;
          if(id=="") {
            $http.get("api/" + tabla).then(function (response) {
              data = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);
              //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);



            }, function(response) {
            });
          } else {
            $http.get("api/" + tabla + "/" + id).then(function (response) {
                data = response.data.data[0];
                //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);
            }, function(response) {
            });
          }
          return data;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

el problema es la asincronidad, no esta esperando que entre a las condicionales , directamente devuelve el return, prueba con:

```
$scope.get = function(id, tabla){
          var data;
          if(id=="") {
            $http.get("api/" + tabla).then(function (response) {
              data = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);
              //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);
              return data;


            }, function(response) {
            });
          } else {
            $http.get("api/" + tabla + "/" + id).then(function (response) {
                data = response.data.data[0];
                return data;
                //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);
            }, function(response) {
            });
          }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces una metodo en angular que requiere consumir un servicio, **este realiza una promesa** por lo cual te devuelve indefinido o algo extraño como $promise; te comento esto para que lo tengas en cuenta para futuros metodos
Una opcion valida es la que te ofrecio **x-rw**, te ofrecere una nueva forma solo para fines educativos

```
$scope.data = [];
$scope.get(1, 8); //ejemplo como si se estuviece consumiendo en el html
$scope.get = function(id, tabla){

          if(id=="") {
            $http.get("api/" + tabla).then(function (response) {
              $scope.data = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);
              //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);



            }, function(response) {
            });
          } else {
            $http.get("api/" + tabla + "/" + id).then(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response.data.data[0];
                //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);
            }, function(response) {
            });
          }
      }
```

ya la variable **data** te queda disponible para cualquier uso dentro del alcance del que tiene la variable **scope** de angular , cuando trabajas con metodos que utilizen promesa (como carga de un json de manera local por ejemplo) tu podrias creer que tu metodo fallo; por el contrario angular y su asincronia lo deja como si estuviece ejecutando en segundo plano, te recomiendo cuando uses metodos que sea solo acciones que tengan que ver con las variables que estan trabajando dentro de la aplicacion que no dependa de una llamada a un servicio

Comment: si eres nuevo en angular hace tiempo un colega publico algo que creo que debas leer un poco http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11323/scope-vs-this-en-angularjs/44904#44904

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Logre resolverlo ya.

Comment: marca el comentario con el que te ayudastes; y si no publicalo para que quede para otras personas

Comment: gracias, ya la he dejado

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolvi de esta manera, gracias por el apoyo

```
$scope.get = function(id, tabla){
          var data;
          var defered = $q.defer();
          var promise = defered.promise;

          if(id=="") {
            $http.get("api/" + tabla).then(function (response) {
              defered.resolve(response.data.data);

              //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);



            }, function(response) {
               defered.reject(response);
            });
          } else {
            $http.get("api/" + tabla + "/" + id).then(function (response) {
                defered.resolve(response.data.data[0]);
                //Materialize.toast(response.data.statusMessage, 4000);
            }, function(response) {
               defered.reject(response);

            });
          }
          return promise;
      }
```

para llamar a la funcion, simplemente la llamo de la siguiente manera.

```
        $scope.get('').then(function(data) {
            $scope.elementos = data;
        })
```

Siempre tienes que declarar en el controlador la cabecera `$q`, sino, no funcionara.

De todas manera, dejo el tutorial por el cual me guie.

https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/uso-de-promesas-en-angularjs/