# Cannot read property of undefined Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Buenas.

Actualmente tengo una vista, de la cual recupero un dato que paso a un component que llama a un servicio. El dato pasa de la vista a la función del component mediante evento click sin ningún problema. Pero cuando va a llamar a la función del servicio muestra un error de que la propiedad es undefined.

Vista:

```
<input #search type="text" ng-model="search">
<button (click)="searchIt(search.value)" class="button is-primary">Search</button>
```

Función del component:

```
searchIt(id: string){
    this.myService.getIt(id)
                        .subscribe(
                            res => {
                                this.content = res;
                            },
                            err => {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        );
}
```

Función del servicio (aun que no llega ni a llamarlo):

```
 getIt(id: string):  Observable<content[]>{
     console.log("Servicio: " + key);
     return this.http.get(this.url + "/" + id)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
 };
```

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: este respuesta es parecida a http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50977/angularjs-me-devuelve-undefined-en-el-return/51007#51007 el error esta que debes realizar una promesa verifca el link si es de tu ayuda

Comment: Pero en angular 2 por lo que he estado viendo se utilizan Observables en vez de Promise. No sé acabo de empezar con angular 2 y no termino de ver donde estaría el problema siguiendo el enlace que me has pasado.

Comment: y este enlace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896798/angularjs-2-official-tutorial-promise-resolve-vs-http

Comment: No estoy seguro de que sea exactamente mi problema. Quiero decir que yo estoy pasando el parametro a la función del componente, pero al pasarla de ahí a mi servicio salta el undefined... Le seguiré echando un ojo al tema de los Observers a ver si veo que es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que injectar el servicio.

```
constructor(public myservice: myService) {

}
```

y Haces referencia al servicio

```
this.myservice.getIt(id)
         .subscribe(
           res => {
               this.content = res;
           },
           err => {
               console.log(err);
           }
         );
```

Comment: Faltaba inyectarlo... Vaya fallo más estupido. Encima en otro componente estaba llamando a otro metodo de ese mismo servicio y no he sido capaz de verlo. Muchas gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

tengo un problema parecido pero en mi casi si estoy inyectando bien el servicio, que creen que pueda ser??? estoy utilizando angular 10 y dejó de funcionar de un día para otro, ya hice ro[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]lback hasta el momento antes de implementarlo y continua el mismo problema, se que esta pregunta es algo vieja pero bueno espero me puedan apoyar un saludo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]